# Ionic2 constructor, two different classes

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm creating a simple page and I need to NavController and AlertController, as far as I understood constructor should look like this:

```
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController 
, navCtrl: NavController) { }
```

my problem is that navController is not recognised later in the code. If I change the line to

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
alertCtrl: AlertController) { }
```

Then `alertController` stops working. Im pretty sure its some newbie syntax issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that import is fine because it works separately. (&only one of the two is used in constructor)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `public` or `private` for both of them individually

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `private` or `public` to the services you want to inject because these are parameter proberties. Adding a modifier allows you to create and initialize a member in the same place.

So your code should look like this:

```
constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  public alertCtrl: AlertController
 ) {}
```

or this:

```
constructor(
  private navCtrl: NavController,
  private alertCtrl: AlertController
 ) {}
```

> Parameter properties are declared by prefixing a constructor parameter with an accessibility modifier or readonly, or both. Using private for a parameter property declares and initializes a private member; likewise, the same is done for public, protected, and readonly.